# How can I create a GridView in android application which can slide left and right

Tags: android

In the car home application, It has 2 panels of grids (2x3) and I can slide left and right using finger flicking. And there is animation during the transition from left to right panels (and vice versa).

Can you please tell me what kind of android widget they use for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that app but is it perhaps using ViewFlipper?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  [**ImageSwitcher widget**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) :

Refer the sample given in "API Demos" coming up itself with Android-SDK: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html

You can also refer this example: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/image-switcher-view-android-developer.html

Comment: But in the car home app, there are 2 grids of images, not just 1 image to another.